# I followed the steps of Google's help, but the credentials do not work

Tags: java, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I'm trying to create a small program that sends emails and used the Java tutorial that Google provides, I made the credentials as in the tutorial but when I squeegee the program pops up the error:

```
com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
ADVERTÊNCIA: unable to change permissions for everybody: C:\Users\HP\.credentials\gmail-java-quickstart
mai 27, 2017 7:40:25 AM com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
ADVERTÊNCIA: unable to change permissions for owner: C:\Users\HP\.credentials\gmail-java-quickstart
:run
Credentials saved to C:\Users\HP\.credentials\gmail-java-quickstart
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Insufficient Permission",
    "reason" : "insufficientPermissions"
  } ],
  "message" : "Insufficient Permission"
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Could you give us the link to the tutorial?

Comment: This link: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java